# Linear Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability

I am reading the high dimensional probability book by Roman and I am trying to understand what they mean by we get at least a  linear convergence in probability from the following:

$$P\{S_N\ge \frac{3}{4}N\}\le \frac{4}{N}.$$

I figure they are referring to the fact that as $N$ grows linearly we get convergence of our probability to 0. So our worst case scenario is linear decay to zero. Is this correct? Does this inequality imply that

$$P\{S_N\ge \frac{3}{4}N\}=o(N)$$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\frac4N$ is $o(N)$ and also $o(1)$, though saying it is $O(\frac1N)$ might be more useful information

Comment: But perhaps the desired statement is that $S_N$ is $O_p(N)$

Comment: @Henry I new to little o big o notation. What would be the appropriate rate when determining the convergence rate of $P\{S_N\ge \frac{3}{4}N\}$ in terms of o notation?

Comment: You could say it is $o(1/N^{1-\varepsilon})$ for all $1>\varepsilon>0$.  If you divide the expression by $1/N^{1-\varepsilon}$, you get that the probability is less or equal than $N^{-\varepsilon}$, which goes to zero as $N \rightarrow \infty$.